# Importar archivo en excel con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, phpexcel

Estimados estoy desarrollando una aplicacion donde tiene un metodo para importar archivo de excel. Estoy utilizando la libreria para laravel de MaatWebSite, pero me muestra un error que creo saber interpretar lo que me esta piediendo pero no encuentro la solucion:

```
{
    "message": "No ReaderType or WriterType could be detected. Make sure you either pass a valid extension to the filename or pass an explicit type.",
    "exception": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Exceptions\\NoTypeDetectedException",
    "file": "F:\\xampp\\htdocs\\carpeta\\carpeta2\\vendor\\maatwebsite\\excel\\src\\Helpers\\FileTypeDetector.php",
    "line": 31,
    "trace": [
```

Sigo los pasos tal cual lo explica la documentacion.
Al archivo lo envio desde un componente de VUejs, es un formulario html con el metodo de envio correspondiente. 
Lo unico que noto es que cuando desde laravel coloco:

```
return $request->excel->getRealPath();
```

Recibo como respuesta `F:\xampp\tmp\phpBD04.tmp`

Supongo que el error que tengo es que no es la extension que la libreria busca...
Alguno me puede ayudar!!

Answer (score 0):

utilizando la librería FastExcel, me daba un error parecido. Lo resolví grabando el archivo en el directorio "local" de laravel.

Mira este código:

```
    public function subir(Request $request) {
         $archivo = $request->file('ArchivoExcel');
         $nombre = $archivo->getClientOriginalName();
         $contenido = \File::get($archivo) ;
         $directorio = \Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() ;
         $fullarchivo = $directorio . $nombre ;

    $grabado = \Storage::disk('local')->put($fullarchivo, $contenido);

    if ($grabado) {
         $datos = (new FastExcel)
                        ->configureCsv(';', '#', '\n', 'UTF-8')
                        ->import($fullarchivo);
   endif
```

La documentación esta en:
https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel

Solo debes agregar esta linea al inicio del controlador:

`use Rap2hpoutre\FastExcel\FastExcel;`

Y de allí puedes utilizar la función subir() configurando la ruta en web.php

Comment: como utilizo esta libreria en laravel?

Comment: Hola William, disculpa la tardanza en responder. He actualizado la respuesta. Si necesitas mas ayuda me avisa.

Answer (score 0):

En ocasiones se debe a que no se esta incluyendo el enctype en el formulario html

a modo de ejemplo:

```
<form action="/action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```